# alert after php-formular has send

Tags: php, html, web

I have a E-Mail formular on my Webside. After the Mail is send i will give the user a feedback. **How can i give the alert on my side with the formular?** 
Now I will be forwarded to sendMail.php with the alerttext writen on the page.

html-code (in index.html):

```
<form ... action="sendMail.php">
   ...
</form>
```

php-code (in sendMail.php):

```
$mail_senden = mail($empfaenger,$betreff,$msg,$header);

if($mail_senden){
  echo "nachricht1";
  exit();
} else{
  echo "nachricht2";
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send message back via `$_GET`. For example

```
<form action="sendMail.php">
    ...
    <?php echo isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : ''; ?>
</form>
```

And in `sendMail.php` write

```
$mail_senden = mail($empfaenger,$betreff,$msg,$header);
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if($mail_senden){
    header("Location: $referer?message=nachricht1");
    exit();
} else {
    header("Location: $referer?message=nachricht2");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge `index.html` and `sendMail.php` so create `index.php` file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){ //check if form was submitted
    $input = $_POST['inputText']; //get input text
    $message = "Success! You entered: ".$input;
}
?>

<html>
    <body>    
        <form action="" method="post">
            <?php echo $message; ?>
            <input type="text" name="inputText"/>
            <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
        </form>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be to use Javascript + JQuery and do something like this:

Add this to index.html

```
<script>
   $("#YourFormID").submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var mailData = $("#YourFormID").serialize();
        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "sendMail.php?"+mailData,
             success: function(html){
                  if(html=='true'){
                      alert("E-Mail sent");
                  }
                  else{
                      alert("E-Mail was not sent";
                  }
        });
        $( "#YourFormID" ).submit();
    }
</script>
```

And in your sendMail.php (YOU need it, but the User doesnt see it)

```
$empfaenger = $_GET['NameOfInputFieldWithThisValue'];
$betreff = $_GET['NameOfInputFieldWithThisValue'];
$msg = $_GET['NameOfInputFieldWithThisValue']; 
$header = $_GET['NameOfInputFieldWithThisValue'];

$mail_senden = mail($empfaenger,$betreff,$msg,$header);

if($mail_senden){
  echo "true";
  exit();
} else{
  echo "false";
  exit();
}
```

Haven't tested it, but I think it should work

PS: You need to include JQuery before your script-Tag opens